# Exit process that started without a terminal

Tags: raspbian

I have the following script in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
omxplayer --loop  --blank video.mp4
```

I double clicked the script and did execute instead of execute in terminal.
I noticed I wasn't able to close the application.

For the purpose of learning, is there any way in that case to close the application?

ctrl + c does not work.
Neither does esc.

Answer (score 1):

You can hit `q` in omxplayer to exit. If you ever don't know how to close an application you can always use `killall applicationname`, so in this case you could have used `killall omxplayer`.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Looks like the right answer.

Comment: This is the edited answer, the previous answer was using `killall` which was not necessary as omxplayer has the `q` keybinding to exit. @DmitryGrigoryev

Comment: But imho you could have let the `kill` part in the answer as an alternative, say if for whatever reason the keybinding is not set or simply for any other generic application.

Comment: Added it @Ghanima

Comment: Where would you type `killall appname`? Since the omxplayer is fullscreen on top.

Comment: @clankill3r Many options, for example you could open a new SSH session, or connect a UART cable, or switch to a virtual terminal if you have a key binding for it. You could even assign a hotkey to `killall omxplayer` command, if it is often needed.

Comment: q does not work.